# Rails - With many-to-many, how to restrict a registred user to like several time an article?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this kind of db:schema :

articles +-------+ article_users +------+ user

How can I restrict an user to vote more than one time on an article ?

Is there a validation rule to put on model for that ?

Comment: You will need to be more specific so we can help you. Paste some code of what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin by replacing to a has_many :through relationship if you're using has_and_belongs_to_many, so that you'll be able to access the relation model, ie. : ArticleUser.

Then first validate the relation model ArticleUser :

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope => :article_id
```

If you want to know if a user has already voted for an article, you can use something like :

```
ArticleUser.exists?(:user_id => @user.id, :article_id => @article.id)
```

or directly using the has_many relation...